# Angular 6 reset select options onclick

Tags: select, angular6, reset, angular-forms

I am trying to reset options value when clicked on button. I was unable to find any solution. I have a component where I am using this code:

```
 <select class='select-option' required [(ngModel)]='optionSelected' (ngModelChange)="toNumber()">
      <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled  selected> Please select one option </option>
      <option *ngFor='let option of options' [ngValue]="option">{{option}}</option>
  </select>
```

Inside my class I am using this code:

```
options = ["Bar", "Pie", "Area"];
```

To call options inside a loop. I am using this code on button event:

```
appendToContainer(){
  // logic 
  this.options  == null
 }
```

What should I do to make it default or null

Comment: what about `this.optionSelected=null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is correct, but implementation is wrong:

```
appendToContainer(){
    // logic 
    this.options == null; // ==> WRONG expression
    this.options = []; // ==> CORRECT
}
```

Comment: You were using == instead of =

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
appendToContainer(){
  // logic 
  this.options.value  == this.options.options.first;//if the first options is 'Select'
}
```